# Unable to install VLC media player and video in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: system

While I am trying to install VLC, I'm getting the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2) but 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.9 is to be installed
     Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.5 is to be installed
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.3-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 is to be installed
     Depends: libva-x11-1 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libva1 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libxcb-composite0 but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libxcb-keysyms1 (>= 0.3.9) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 ============================================================
```

Also, while I am trying to open a video using "open with videos", I'm getting the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gstreamer1.0-libav: Depends: libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.13) but 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libavformat54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libavutil52 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.9 is to be installed
                    Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try Synaptic Package Manager

Have you tried to install VLC using the Synaptic Package Manager? Download the Synaptic from the Software Center or from [here](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/System/Software-Distribution/Synaptic-2028.shtml) and search for VLC. If you have it installed on your system it will show you what version you have installed. Mark VLC (if it is installed) for complete removal (VLC only) and hit apply. After it has been removed search again for VLC and this time mark it for installation.It will automatically mark unmet dependencies. Click apply to install it again.

#### For the videos

For the videos goto the software center and search for videos and click on more info. Check the GStreamer codec install in the Optional add-ons and click apply change.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Using another package manager application won't solve the unmet dependencies errors in the question.